# How is the legroom in an Emirates A380/777-300ER?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, emirates

I'm flying from Brussels to Auckland with Emirates, which is two flights, one of 7 hours, and one 19 hour long flight. 
I'm also 2 meters tall (6'7"), so I always prefer to book an emergency exit seat whenever possible.

However, Emirates charges a whopping EUR 87 (for the 7 hour flight) and EUR 136 (for the 19 hour flight) to book a seat with extra legroom.

In total, that would be close to EUR 450 (87 to and from, and 136 to and from).

Are these seats really worth the price? Or is the legroom in the regular seats large enough for tall people like me to sit comfortably anyway?

Comment: Have you checked SeatGuru to find out the seating pitch?

Comment: Yes, and it says 32-34. However, I have no idea what that means, or if it's enough. One of the comments I read said that it's not enough, but others say it's spacious.

Comment: Whether the increased legroom is "worth the price" or "large enough for tall people" are both ultimately matters of opinion, and preference, and personal tolerance of discomfort, and ability or willingness to pay.. People have different opinions about things; your opinions may well be different from mine.

Comment: I would compare your past experiences of legroom, look up the seat pitch in those seats, to make the determination of whether the seat pitch of your upcoming flight will be adequate.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica That's perfectly true, but not very helpful if the OP hasn't previously flown 19 hours in economy before and has not found his personal tolerance level out the hard way yet.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I think it's useful to point out that some of the matters about which the OP asks are opinions. In a practical sense, your Answer is indeed much more responsive and useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Economy class legroom in commercial airlines **typically varies from 28" to 34"**, so if SeatGuru's saying 32-34", that's definitely at the generous end of the scale.  That said, sybaritic luxury it's not.

As a fellow tall person (but not quite as a tall as you), I find under 30" to be tough going, although it's tolerable for short haul.  32" is OK for most flights, but I recently flew a 15-hour long-haul in Singapore Airlines with that pitch and it was pretty squished, especially when the person in front reclined: I had to spread or tilt my legs because I couldn't sit straight, and I could not comfortably use my laptop because the screen was too close and my elbows hit the seat if I tried to use its keyboard.  But on the way back, I was on ANA in a 34" seat, and it was comparatively comfortable.

So in your figurative shoes, **I would probably pony up for the upgrade**, at least for the 19-hour ultramarathon which is literally [among the world's longest flights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_flights#Longest_passenger_flights).  At €136, it's less than €10 per hour, or the cost of an extra night at a hotel.

Comment: I've decided to go for the upgrade. I've done a long haul flight without upgrade before, and it was agony.